# Selenium does not find an element

Tags: java, selenium, testing, webdriver

I am writing a test in Java and somehow Selenium cannot find the element with name 0108:

```
<div id="appmngTabs">
<ul id="menu">
<li name="0101">
<li name="0102">
<li name="0103">
<li name="0104">
<li name="0105">
<li name="0106" class="activ">
<li name="0107">
<li name="0108">
<a onfocus="disableFocus()" onclick="focusTab('0108')" target="content" href="applMenu?mode=cnt&menu=EOB2B&uni=0108" name="0108">Interfacing</a>
</li>
<li name="0109">
<li name="0199">
```

I don't see anything special in this HTML code, but Selenium cannot click on it. What I have tried:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("0108")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[name=0108]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li[name=0108]")).click();
```

I have tried combinations like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("menu").name("0108")).click();
```

Still nothing. Am I doing something wrong?

UPDATE: frame:

```
<frame id="menu" noresize="" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" name="menu" src="applMenu?menu=EOB2B">
```

UPDATE 2: frame/frameset

```
<frameset framespacing="0" frameborder="0" rows="144,*">
<frame id="menu" noresize="" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" name="menu" src="applMenu?menu=EOB2B">
<frame id="content" noresize="" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0" name="content" src="applMenu?mode=cnt&menu=EOB2B">
</frameset>
```

UPDATE 3: AJAX
I have been told that the problem might be with loading ajax, I have added this:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 35);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.name("0108")));
```

But it did not help either.

UPDATE 4: HtmlDriver vs. FireforDriver.
I have used html driver while running the test, but I tried firefox driver to see what is really happeinig and after opening the page, error *document could not be opened* appeared, while using selenium ide, there was no issue - test went fine.

What should I do?

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Yes: "NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element"

Comment: Check if the element is inside an `iframe` or not.

Comment: Yes I can click on it and I tried Selenium IDE and it finds it but when I write a code in Eclipse the button cannot be found.

Comment: I added to the Question

Answer (score 2):

Since the element is inside the `frame`, *switch to it* before issuing `findElement()`:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("menu");
driver.findElement(By.name("0108")).click();
```

When you need to go back into the context of the main document:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

<sup>Note that you may also need to click the menu to open it up before clicking the submenu.</sup>

Comment: Now it says: "Unable to locate frame..."

Comment: @k.horde okay, could it be that you've got nested frames?

Comment: If I understand correctly, then yes. Nested Frames is when you have a part of the website which changes and the rest is static? Sorry, I am not a HTML master :)

Comment: @k.horde nono, I mean this frame with `id="menu"` is it itself inside an another frame?

Comment: @k.horde quick check, what if you put `driver.switchTo().frame(0);` before the `driver.switchTo().frame("menu");`?

Comment: unfortunately, selenium says: _NoSuchFrame: 0_

Answer (score -2):

Try by XPath

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@name='108']"))
```

EDIT:

If you really need to find by cssselector

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li[name=\"0108\"]")).click();
```

should work.

Comment: you suggest to use same identifier with different method- this will not do the trick

Comment: @Andersson no reason to downvote as this works for me. OP didn't mention he is using frames...